# Transforming a Javascript-array based on multiple factors

Tags: javascript, arrays, parsing, statistics

This will be a bit of a long question, but bear with me, I'll try to explain it.
For a simple statistics exercise, I'm trying to read in a certain dataset, but the data is formatted quite weirdly. Let's start off with an example data-array. The data is internally organised on 8-block numbers.

```
[101, 103, 253, 253, 253, 102, 104, 254, 73, 32, 100, 111, 110, 39, 116, 32, 107, 110, 111, 119, 32, 119, 104, 97, 116, 32, 105, 115, 32, 32, 32, 32, 254, 254, 101, 102, 254, 254, 254, 0]
```

In the data file, there are a few cases and a few variables (in this case 3 variables and 3 cases. A case can be seen as a 'respondent' to a questionnaire).

The variables look like this (only some values are relevant)

```
Variable A: Length 8 (regular number)
Variable B: Length 8 (regular number)
Variable C: Length 20 (string)
```

What this means is that Variable A will take up one byte, Variable B will as well, and Variable C will take up 3 bytes (ceil(20/8)).

If a value is between 1 and 251, I need to use 'value - a certain bias. In this case 100'

As of this point, the data will be as such:

```
Case 1 Variable A: 1
Case 1 Variable B: 3
```

However, not every single value fits in 'one byte'. Variable C for instance is a String variable, and will probably have multiple bytes. That's where a `253` value comes in.

A value of `253` means: 'the next block of 8 bytes will be the value of this variable'. Multiple values of 253 will mean that there will be multiple blocks for that one value. In this case we know Variable C needs 3 bytes. All those 3 bytes are value `253`, so we know that we need to read 3 blocks of 8 bytes after this block.

Starting from the 8th element of the array, that will be:

```
[73, 32, 100, 111, 110, 39, 116, 32, 107, 110, 111, 119, 32, 119, 104, 97, 116, 32, 105, 115, 32, 32, 32, 32]
```

Converting that to a string gives us:

'I don't know what is'

So at this point the data will be as such:

```
Case 1 Variable A: 1
Case 1 Variable B: 3
Case 1 Variable C: 'I don't know what is'
```

After that we continue with the data. We stopped at the last 253, so now there are two more numbers (102 and 104, meaning 2 and 4).

At this point the data will be as such:

```
Case 1 Variable A: 1
Case 1 Variable B: 3
Case 1 Variable C: 'I don't know what is'
Case 2 Variable A: 2
Case 2 Variable B: 4
```

Now we see a value of 254. This means an 'empty string'. Make note that variable C (the current variable) is 3 bytes long. We only have 1 byte left in this block. So we need to skip over the blocks already read, and read two more bytes there. That next block is:

```
[254, 254, 101, 102, 254, 254, 254, 0]
```

That would make the value of Case 2 Variable C 254, 254, 254 resulting in the following dataset:

```
Case 1 Variable A: 1
Case 1 Variable B: 3
Case 1 Variable C: 'I don't know what is'
Case 2 Variable A: 2
Case 2 Variable B: 4
Case 2 Variable C: ''
```

After that we have a few more values to interpret, making the ending dataset:

```
Case 1 Variable A: 1 - (101)
Case 1 Variable B: 3 - (103) 
Case 1 Variable C: 'I don't know what is' (253, 253, 253 = read 3 blocks: [73, 32, 100, 111, 110, 39, 116, 32, 107, 110, 111, 119, 32, 119, 104, 97, 116, 32, 105, 115, 32, 32, 32, 32]
Case 2 Variable A: 2 - (102)
Case 2 Variable B: 4 - (104)
Case 2 Variable C: '' - (254, 254, 254)
Case 3 Variable A: 1 - (101)
Case 3 Variable B: 2 - (102)
Case 3 Variable C: '' - (254, 254, 254)
```

Doing this by head seems very easy. Doing this programatically has been something I couldn't wrap my head around. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I lost you at "A value of 253 means: 'the next block of 8 bytes will be the value of this variable'". That means to me: Read the next three blocks of 8 byte after the 253,253,253 sequence, which is 102, 104, 254. Why would I skip this?

Comment: The data is organized in 8-byte blocks. As we're in the first block while reading the 253,253,253 sequence, this means: 'read the second, third and fourth block'. They went really out of their way to align it all on the 8-byte blocks.

Comment: What happens to the remaining data in the block. For example, the first block is [101, 103, 253, 253, 253, 102, 104, 254]. What happens to the 102, 104, and 254?

Comment: Never mind, I get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should have at least 3 pointers:

```
curblock = 0; // current 8 byte block
ptr = 0; // byte in current 8 byte block
nextblock = 8; // next 8 byte block
```

And two functions readNumber() and readString() that read from the array according to these pointers, and of course update those pointers. Hints:

```
... 
if(ch == 253) {
    // my_tostring() must be implemented
    str += my_tostring(data.slice(nextblock, nextblock+8));
    nextblock += 8;
}

...
ptr++;
if(ptr == 8) { ptr=0; curblock=nextblock; nextblock+=8; }
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed and fixed the problem entirely! Also finished the project now, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear about how you're converting the value for C into a string, but this code will get you 90% of the way there:

```
function Reader(array){
    this.blocks = [];

    while(array.length){
        this.blocks.push(array.splice(0,8));
    }

    this._currentBlock = this.nextBlock();
}
Reader.prototype = {
    currentBlock: function(){
        if(!this._currentBlock.length){
            this._currentBlock = this.nextBlock();
        }
        return this._currentBlock;
    },
    readNext: function(count){
        count = count || 1;
        var output = [];

        while(count--){
            var value = this.currentBlock().shift();

            switch(value){
                case 253: value = this.nextBlock(); break;
                case 254: value = []; break;
                default : value = [value]; break;
            }

            output = output.concat(value);
        }

        return output;
    },
    nextBlock: function(){
        return this.blocks.shift();
    },
    peek: function(){
        return this._currentBlock[0];
    },
    buildCases: function(){
        var cases = [];

        do{
            var obj = {};
            var i = cases.length + 1;

            obj['Case ' + i + 'Variable A'] = this.readNext();
            obj['Case ' + i + 'Variable B'] = this.readNext();
            obj['Case ' + i + 'Variable C'] = this.readNext(3);

            cases.push(obj);
        }
        while(this.peek() !== 0);

        return cases;
    }
};

var reader = new Reader([101, 103, 253, 253, 253, 102, 104, 254, 73, 32, 100, 111, 110, 39, 116, 32, 107, 110, 111, 119, 32, 119, 104, 97, 116, 32, 105, 115, 32, 32, 32, 32, 254, 254, 101, 102, 254, 254, 254, 0]);
var cases = reader.buildCases();
```

Comment: Wow, that is beautiful. I see you found this data structure weird enough to take the effort to tame it. As I see, a trailing 0 must be added to the input array, and Variable A cannot be 0.

Comment: THANKS! This algorithm does a check for the 0 in the buildCases method after each case is read into the data structure (hence the peek). It assumes that there are no abnormalities in the input data. Your code is much more succinct (and faster). I might merge the two later and see what I come up with.